# How to specify explicit document id in elasticsearch while performing a bulk index operation?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have to perform a bulk index operation in elasticsearch.
The data looks like

```
[{'code': 12, 'name': 'ABC', 'designation': 'ceo'}, 
 {'code': 13, 'name': 'AIB', 'designation': 'cfo'}, 
 {'code': 14, 'name': 'AXB', 'designation': 'cto'}]
```

While indexing i want to explicitly provide code as the id. It is simple when performing single indexing operation. I am not sure as to how can it be done in bulk index operation.

Answer (score 1):

For indexing the format is different for bulk. There need to be 2 lines per index request. First one for meta data like indexname , type name and ID and second one , actual data -

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
```

You can specify the id in the first field.
You can read more on this [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html).

Comment: Thank you very much it was my ignorance that I missed it.